# Icon drawable in a Button with API lower 21

Tags: android, android-layout, android-vectordrawable

I have two activities, `AddActivty` and `ViewActivity`. These two activities share a layout view defined in the file `layout_form.xml`.

First of all, my app requires to work a **minimum sdk version 16**. So in the `build.gradle` file I specified that.

These is a snipped of the `layout_form.xml`. Remaining code is not important.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="orizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/leftToolbarButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_done"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_done"
            android:text="ADD"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/rightToolbarButton"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_cancel"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_cancel"
            android:text="CANCEL"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</Toolbar>
```

In both activities I set this layout as the content view by the line
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_form);

This is how my app toolbar looks when `AddActivity` is on screen.

[image]

and so far, so good.

Problems arise when I start `ViewActivity`.
This is the code of in its `onCreate()` method.

```
Button backButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.leftToolbarButton);
backButton.setText("BACK");
//PROBLEM HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
backButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
    R.drawable.ic_back, 0, 0, 0);

Button editButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.rightToolbarButton);
editButton.setText("EDIT");
//AND PROBLEM HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
editButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
0, 0, R.drawable.ic_edit, 0);
```

Now, if I run my app on android >=21 all is ok. This is how toolbar should be.

[image]

Instead, on android 16 it looks in this way.

[image]

As you can see, if my app is running on Android 16 (I don't know what happens on Android 17 or above, but lower than 21)
Icon are not changed. They still look the same of those set in xml layout file.

Another thing. I add this listener to the `editButton`

```
editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        backButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
        R.drawable.ic_back, 0, 0, 0);
    }
});
```

If I click on it, now icon changes.

[image]

So, why in the `onCreate()` method of `ViewActivity` don't icons change?

Answer (score 1):

Solved!
The problem are

```
android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_done"
```

in `leftToolbarButton`, and

```
android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_cancel"
```

in `rightToolbarButton`.

I moved out these two lines from layout_form.xml.
I added them because Android Studio suggested me to add them in order to better support left-to-right layout.